# How to implement helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I am having a really difficult time implementing a helper in my application. Firstly the site I'm working on does not seem to conform to standard ruby on rails rules. It was developed by someone who no longer works at the company so I cant ask any questions. There isnt an application controller or any reference to one in the code. I have the following code in a helper file (app/helpers/service_helper.rb)

```
# Check IP and expiry time
def logged_in?
  u = session[:user]
  ip = @env['REMOTE_ADDR']

  if u.present? and u.ip == ip and u.expiry > Time.now

    if Database.instance.call('IBCheckSession', u.id, ip) == 0 then
      logout
      return false
    end

    session[:user].expiry += 300
    return true
  end
  false
end
```

This then gets called in a variety of views eg:

```
%nav#user
  - if logged_in?
    %ul
      %li.name
        %span#customername= @customer.name
        %ul
          %li= link_to 'Settings', '/settings', class: :settings
      %li
        %span#timeout
      %li.logout= link_to 'Logout', '/logout'
```

I am continually getting a nomethoderror. I have been working at this for a day now and my head is spinning. Could someone please explain what i need to do or what i am doing wrong or give me some indication of what alternative approach i could take.

Comment: What do you mean by “get it working”? What kind of error you are getting? What’s the desired behaviour?

Comment: @mudasobwa Apologies. I get a nomethoderror undefined method error.

Comment: Is there a app/helpers/application_helper.rb? If yes just add "include ServiceHelper" in the helper definition

Comment: @ssuljic No there isnt. There is a helpers.rb, service_helpers.rb and extensions.rb. Should i create one. Again the structure of this project seems quite out of tune with any examples i have seen.